# Comparing two objects properties but not working propery

Tags: javascript

Here is my code. I know it's not entirely strict but please shed some light on why the let...in does not work properly here.

```js
const object1 = {here: 1, object: 3};
const obj = {here: 1, object: 2};

function comp(a, b) {
  if (typeof a == typeof b) {
    let arra = Object.keys(a);
    let arrb = Object.keys(b);
    for (let key in arra){
      if (a[key] == b[key]) return true
    }
        return false
  }
}

console.log(comp(obj, object1))
```

The above prints `true` but it is supposed to print `false`

Comment: You should give more informations, what is not working properly, what were you expecting, what did you get...

Comment: Your code should output true because the keys present in both objects are the same.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt no, it should output `false` because even though the two have the same *keys*, they don't have the same *values*.

Comment: You should use `for..of` instead of `for..in` which is only for objects. You're reading array indices right now, not key names. `Object.keys` returns Arrays, not objects.

Comment: you should add a check for null as `typeof null === "object"`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski there is a lot more problems, e.g., `comp({1: "a", 2: "b"}, {1: "a" , 2: "b", 3: "c" })`  will return `true. However, I think OP is aware that this isn't perfect and is just searching for a solution to the current problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting `true` because you `return true` *in* your `for` loop whenever a key value from one object equals the key-value pair of another object. So when your code sees the `here` property, it will `return true`, thus stopping your function from running any further code.

You need to remove this check, and only `return false` in your for loop, such that your for loop will only complete if it never returns (ie: all key-value pairs are equal).

Moreover, the `for..in` loop will loop over the keys in an object, so, there is no need to get the keys of your objects (using `Object.keys`) into an array (as then you'll be looping over the keys of an array (ie: the indexes)).

However, with that being said, you can use `Object.keys` to help with another issue. You can use it to get the number of properties in both objects, as you know the two objects are not the same if they don't have the same number of properties in them

See example below:

```js
const object1 = {
  here: 1,
  object: 3
};
const obj = {
  here: 1,
  object: 3
};

function comp(a, b) {
  if (typeof a == typeof b) {
    if(Object.keys(a).length !== Object.keys(b).length) {
      return false; // return false (stop fruther code execution)
    }
  
    for (let key in a) { // loop through the properties of larger object (here I've chosen 'a') - no need for Object.keys
      if (a[key] != b[key]) 
        return false; // return false (stops any further code executing)
    }
    return true; // we only reach this point if the for loop never returned false
  }
  return false; // we reach this point when the two types don't match, and so we can say they're not equal
}

console.log(comp(obj, object1))
```

Comment: Will return true, if b is the same as a, but b has one extra property,

Comment: @MauriceNino good point, I've added a fix for this now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
for (let key in arra){
      if (a[key] == b[key]) return true
    }
        return false
  }
```

You should perform the exact opposite while iterating through the object:

```
for (let key in a){ // a not arra
      if (a[key] !== b[key]) return false
    }
        return true
  }
```

And ommit these lines:

```
let arra = Object.keys(a);
let arrb = Object.keys(b);
```

Comment: So the logic here is if for any key doesn't match, then it's false. Otherwise, it's true. I changed the code but the console.log still shows true :(

Comment: This answer is wrong; The crux of the problem is the use of the wrong type of loop.

Comment: if you omit the two lines `arra` will be undefined.

Comment: Fixed everyting, Nick Parsons's answer is better explained.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for actual values and not property names.

Also, you need to check if `b` has more properties than `a`, because if it is the same, but has one property more, it will still output `true`.

```js
const tester = {here: 1, object: 3};
const obj1 = {here: 1, object: 2};
const obj2 = {here: 1, object: 3};
const obj3 = {here: 1, object: 3, test: 1};
const obj4 = {here: 1, test: 1};

function comp(a, b) {
  if (typeof a == typeof b && Object.keys(a).length == Object.keys(b).length) { // Check for the length of the keys array, because if the length is different, they might have different properties
    // Dont use Object.keys here. You don't need the keys, you need the objects
    for (let key in a){
      if (a[key] != b[key]) 
        return false; // If one key property of a does not match b, return false
    }
    return true; // If nothing returns false, return true
  }
  return false; // If they are not the same type, return false
}

console.log(comp(tester, obj1))
console.log(comp(tester, obj2))
console.log(comp(tester, obj3))
console.log(comp(tester, obj4))
```

Comment: The crux of the problem is the wrong type of loop. The OP (and you) shouldn't use `for..in` to iterate over Arrays.

Comment: @NikKyriakides This is not an array,,,

Comment: Ah gotcha; Sorry I skimmed too fast. Nevertheless it would help to pinpoint to the OP what the problem was. I'm cancelling my downvote.

Comment: @NikKyriakides The first line in my answer explains the basics, about what is wrong. The second one explains a part of the code and the code itself is commented, to explain every step. What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (or just a plain old `for`) instead of [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) which is only used on Objects. You're reading array indices right now, not actual key names. [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an `Array` of key names, not an `Object`.

Also stop returning early; Right now you return immediately after the first key check.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function can be used as below:

```js
const object1 = {here: 1, object: 3, r:4};
const obj = {here: 1, r:4, object: 3};

function comp(a, b) {
  if (typeof a == typeof b) {
    let arra = Object.keys(a);
    return !arra.some(key => { return a[key] != b[key] })
  }
}

console.log(comp(obj, object1))
```